# In Windows 10, how can I swap the alt and win keys *on one specific keyboard*?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, boot-camp, modifier-keys

I recently installed Windows 10 Pro on my Mac via Boot Camp. The left-hand modifier keys on the internal keyboard are, from left to right, Control, Option, and Command. Apple somehow has this configured so that Option is treated as Alt, and Command is treated as Win. I'd like to switch these two keys, but *only on the internal keyboard* -- I also use an external USB keyboard, with the keys in the typical Windows order, and that already works correctly.

I looked around and couldn't find a good way to do this -- AutoHotKey and SharpKeys seem to affect all input, from what I've read. Any suggestions? I can't imagine I'm the first person to be tripped up by this...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not really a fix, but I was able to work around this when I realized that my external keyboard was programmable. I configured it to swap the alt and ctrl keys to the "wrong" locations, matching those on the internal keyboards, and then mapped everything how I want it using SharpKeys. Peachy.

Comment: For other people who see this thread, [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/) can be used to change a keyboard's layout from the keyboard side, not the windows side, ergo making it keyboard specific.